# separate csv columns while a row of cell have different number of elements

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file that look like this:

[image: Original csv]

I want to convert it to something like this:

[image: Converted csv]

The issue is that the first row of each column has 4 elements, while the rest of the rows have 7 elements. I want to keep them aligned. also I want to keep the original column separation.

Anyone have any ideas for how to achieve this?